# How do I correctly reproject a geodataframe with multiple geometry colums?

Tags: python, geopandas, reprojection-error

In [the geopandas documentation](https://geopandas.org/data_structures.html) it says that

> A `GeoDataFrame` may also contain other columns with geometrical (shapely) objects, but only one column can be the active geometry at a time. To change which column is the active geometry column, use the `set_geometry` method.

I'm wondering how to use such a GeoDataFrame if the goal is to flexibly **reproject** the geometrical data in these various columns to one or more other coordinate reference systems. Here's what I tried.

#### First try

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point

crs_lonlat = 'epsg:4326'        #geometries entered in this crs (lon, lat in degrees)
crs_new = 'epsg:3395'           #geometries needed in (among others) this crs
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(crs=crs_lonlat)      
gdf['geom1'] = [Point(9,53), Point(9,54)]     
gdf['geom2'] = [Point(8,63), Point(8,64)]

#Working: setting geometry and reprojecting for first time.
gdf = gdf.set_geometry('geom1')
gdf = gdf.to_crs(crs_new)   #geom1 is reprojected to crs_new, geom2 still in crs_lonlat
gdf
Out: 
                             geom1          geom2
0  POINT (1001875.417 6948849.385)  POINT (8 63)
1  POINT (1001875.417 7135562.568)  POINT (8 64)

gdf.crs
Out: 'epsg:3395'
```

So far, so good. Things go off the rails if I want to set `geom2` as the geometry column, and reproject that one as well:

```
#Not working: setting geometry and reprojecting for second time.
gdf = gdf.set_geometry('geom2')     #still in crs_lonlat...
gdf.crs                             #...but this still says crs_new...
Out: 'epsg:3395'

gdf = gdf.to_crs(crs_new)           #...so this doesn't do anything! (geom2 unchanged)
gdf
Out: 
                             geom1                      geom2
0  POINT (1001875.417 6948849.385)  POINT (8.00000 63.00000)
1  POINT (1001875.417 7135562.568)  POINT (8.00000 64.00000)
```

Ok, so, apparently, the `.crs` attribute of the `gdf` is not reset to its original value when changing the column that serves as the geometry - it seems, the crs is not stored for the individual columns. If that is the case, the only way I see to use reprojection with this dataframe, is to backtrack: start --> select column as geometry --> reproject gdf to crs_new --> use/visualize/... --> reproject gdf back to crs_lonlat --> goto start. This is not usable if I want to visualise both columns in one figure.

#### Second try

My second attempt was, to store the `crs` with each column separately, by changing the corresponding lines in the script above to:

```
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame()
gdf['geom1'] = gpd.GeoSeries([Point(9,53), Point(9,54)], crs=crs_lonlat)
gdf['geom2'] = gpd.GeoSeries([Point(8,63), Point(8,64)], crs=crs_lonlat)
```

However, it soon became clear that, though initialised as a `GeoSeries`, these columns are normal `pandas` `Series`, and don't have a `.crs` attribute the same way `GeoSeries` do:

```
gdf['geom1'].crs
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'crs'

s = gpd.GeoSeries([Point(9,53), Point(9,54)], crs=crs_lonlat)
s.crs
Out: 'epsg:4326'
```

**Is there something I'm missing here?**

Is the only solution, to decide on the 'final' crs beforehand - and do all the reprojecting before adding the columns? Like so...

```
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(crs=crs_new)
gdf['geom1'] = gpd.GeoSeries([Point(9,53), Point(9,54)], crs=crs_lonlat).to_crs(crs_new)
gdf['geom2'] = gpd.GeoSeries([Point(8,63), Point(8,64)], crs=crs_lonlat).to_crs(crs_new)
#no more reprojecting done/necessary/possible! :/
```

...and then, when another crs is needed, rebuild the entire `gdf` from scratch? That can't be the way this was intended to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the desired behaviour is currently not possible. Due to limitations in the package, `geopandas` does not accommodate this use case at the moment, as can be seen in [this issue in the github repo](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/1193).

My workaround is to not use a `GeoDataFrame` at all, but rather combine a normal `pandas` `DataFrame`, for the non-shapely data, with several seperate `geopandas` `GeoSeries`, for the shapely geometry data. The `GeoSeries` each have their own crs and can be correctly reprojected whenever necessary.